# Punctuation Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

First, i'm read the documentation as follow

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

And i want find any punctuation character EXCEPT @',& but i don't quite understand.

Here is :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{       
     // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
     String value = "#`~!#$%^";
     String pattern = "\\p{Punct}[^@',&]";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(value);
    if (m.find()) {
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m.groupCount());
    } else {
       System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }


}
```

Result is NO MATCH. 
Is there any mismatch ?

Thanks
MRizq

Comment: `String pattern = "[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";` should work

Comment: @RC Can you point me to some documentation regarding this syntax? I have never seen it before.

Comment: @Tomalak see the link provided in the question.

Comment: @RC Thanks. I was unaware of character class intersections. Nice to know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're matching two characters, not one. Using a (negative) lookahead should solve the task:

```
(?![@',&])\\p{Punct}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [*character subtraction*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) here:

```
String pat = "[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
```

The whole pattern represents a character class, `[...]`, that contains a `\p{Punct}` [POSIX character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix), the `&&` [intersection operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc) and `[^...]` [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

A Unicode modifier might be necessary if you plan to also match all Unicode punctuation:

```
String pat = "(?U)[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
              ^^^^
```

The pattern matches any punctuation (with `\p{Punct}`) except `@`, `'`, `,` and `&`.

If you need to exclude more characters, add them to the negated character class. Just remember to always escape `-`, `\`, `^`, `[` and `]` inside a Java regex character class/set. E.g. adding a backslash and `-` might look like `"[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&\\\\-]]"` or `"[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&\\-\\\\]]"`.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/i229Io):

```
String value = "#`~!#$%^，";
String pattern = "(?U)[\\p{Punct}&&[^@',&]]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);    // Create a Pattern object
Matcher m = r.matcher(value);            // Now create matcher object.
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
Found value: #
Found value: !
Found value: #
Found value: %
Found value: ，
```