# How to replace all the punctuation except double quotes using RegExp

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to do some string cleanup.

I want to remove all the punctuation from the string **except** double quotes.

Below trimPunctuation() function works great in removing all the punctuation from the string.

Does anyone know a way to remove all the punctuation but the double quotes.

```
 private String trimPunctuation( String string, boolean onlyOnce )
    {
        if ( onlyOnce )
        {
            string = string.replaceAll( "\\p{Punct}$", "" );
            string = string.replaceAll( "^\\p{Punct}", "" );
        }
        else
        {
            string = string.replaceAll( "\\p{Punct}+$", "" );
            string = string.replaceAll( "^\\p{Punct}+", "" );
        }
        return string.trim();
    }
```

More info on Punctuation unicode class can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). But, that didn't help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Punctuation Regex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200908/punctuation-regex-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, the link you provided helped me to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?!")\\p{punct}
```

[Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/eGo54umjLD)

[Java example](http://ideone.com/2ZOTZ):

```
String string = ".\"'";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(?!\")\\p{Punct}", ""));
```

---

Comment: Thanks a ton Niklas B. and FakeRainBrigand for a prompt and very informative responses.