# Efficiently removing specific characters (some punctuation) from Strings in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java, what is the most efficient way of removing given characters from a String? Currently, I have this code:

```
private static String processWord(String x) {
    String tmp;

    tmp = x.toLowerCase();
    tmp = tmp.replace(",", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace(".", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace(";", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("!", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("?", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("(", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace(")", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("{", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("}", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("[", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("]", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("<", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace(">", "");
    tmp = tmp.replace("%", "");

    return tmp;
}
```

Would it be faster if I used some sort of StringBuilder, or a regex, or maybe something else? Yes, I know: profile it and see, but I hope someone can provide an answer of the top of their head, as this is a common task.

Comment: In general Java Regex's perform pretty well and unless I was doing something very performance sensitive I usually just use'm and move on. Also a tmp.replaceAll("\\W", "") will get rid of punctuation and white space in a String.

Comment: Clarification request: Please define what you mean by *punctuation*.  Is it _just_ those characters you list above?  What about em dashes?  What about the curly quotes? What about quote symbols from non-English languages?

Comment: Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) next time you may able to find solution regarding regex by your own.

Comment: additionally this may help you too http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @Pshemo There is no DIRECT answer there. But it will help to understand other than copying.. and next time he may find way to solve this kind of things. I never say that will be the ANSWER. I said this may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373431/removing-certain-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a late answer, just for fun.

In cases like this, I would suggest aiming for readability over speed.  Of course you can be super-readable but too slow, as in this super-concise version:

```
private static String processWord(String x) {
    return x.replaceAll("[][(){},.;!?<>%]", "");
}
```

This is slow because everytime you call this method, the regex will be compiled.  So you can pre-compile the regex.

```
private static final Pattern UNDESIRABLES = Pattern.compile("[][(){},.;!?<>%]");

private static String processWord(String x) {
    return UNDESIRABLES.matcher(x).replaceAll("");
}
```

This should be fast enough for most purposes, assuming the JVM's regex engine optimizes the character class lookup.  This is the solution I would use, personally.

Now without profiling, I wouldn't know whether you could do better by making your own character (actually codepoint) lookup table:

```
private static final boolean[] CHARS_TO_KEEP = new boolean[];
```

Fill this once and then iterate, making your resulting string.  I'll leave the code to you. :)

Again, I wouldn't dive into this kind of optimization.  The code has become too hard to read.  Is performance that much of a concern?  Also remember that modern languages are JITted and after warming up they will perform better, so use a good profiler.

One thing that should be mentioned is that the example in the original question is highly non-performant because you are creating a whole bunch of temporary strings!  Unless a compiler optimizes all that away, that particular solution will perform the worst.

Comment: This is not *quite* true: the regex given, "[][(){},.;!?<>%]", is not valid, as it contains special characters. However, quoting with \Q and \E works nicely: ""[\\Q][(){},.;!?<>%\\E]" (backslashes doubled because Java). I'm going to accept this answer, as it is the one I ended up using, and all alternatives were clearly explained; not to mention only the exact characters mentioned are being removed by this.

Comment: Negative lookaheads is a great addition to this which I found on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880941/how-to-replace-all-the-punctuation-except-double-quotes-using-regexp. This pattern: "(?![._])\\p{Punct}" removes all punctuation in the Punct class except ._ This is good if you want to remove all punct but preserve a few characters.

Answer (score 18):

Although `\\p{Punct}` will specify a wider range of characters than in the question, it does allow for a shorter replacement expression:

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
```

Comment: Did you try `\p{P}` to capture non-ASCII punctuation?  `P` is the Unicode category for punctuation.

Comment: Hmm, tried that but it left some of the original characters behind (such as `>`) so will stick with this :)

Comment: Yeah, I never trusted the single-letter Unicode categories except for `L` :) The reason for that, though, is that `<` is in category SYMBOL (S), _not_ PUNCTUATION (P).  That is why I asked the OP to define "punctuation".

Comment: Do you think'\\p{Punct}' would be implemented more efficiently than just specifying [.,!<>{}] (and the others), as a character class?

Comment: @VPeric +1 good comment. Both the quote (U+0022) and the apostrophe (U+0027) are considered punctuation by both the pattern `\p{Punct}` and `\p{P}`.  The OP did not list those values.  That's why the question needs to be clarified.  It was unfortunate that the OP chose the word "punctuation" and didn't say whether that meant "any punctutation" or just certain characters.  It is a pretty hard question to answer definitively.

Comment: Would need to see microbenchmark figures to say for sure but chances are they would be comparable. To acheive the most performant result you would have to implement a non-regex solution

Comment: @RayToal Actually, I'm the OP. I clarified the question, I hope you find it clearer now.

Comment: @VPeric I see, thanks! The _clearest_ answer is `x.replaceAll("[][(){},.;!?<>%]", "")` but that is slow if done multiple times. Speed it up by compiling a regex with the pattern `[][(){},.;!?<>%]` then do `p.matcher(x).replaceAll("")`.  If you are trying to squeeze every last machine cycle out of your code then you can create a 65536 element boolean array containing `true` for each codepoint to keep and `false` for the ones to throw out, then iterate your string, making a new one.  Being pedantic here, this could fail on surrogates and Unicode combining chars, but so what. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
static String RemovePunct(String input) 
{
    char[] output = new char[input.length()];
    int i = 0;

    for (char ch : input.toCharArray())
    {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || Character.isWhitespace(ch)) 
        {
            output[i++] = ch;
        }        
    }

    return new String(output, 0, i);
}

// ...

String s = RemovePunct("This is (a) test string.");
```

This will likely perform better than using regular expressions, if you find them to slow for your needs.

However, it could get messy fast if you have a long, distinct list of special characters you'd like to remove. In this case regular expressions are easier to handle.

http://ideone.com/mS8Irl

Comment: +1 for going after "most efficient" and giving the best interpretation of what the OP _probably_ meant by the very vague term "punctuation".  Nicely done.

Comment: I think the return line should read: return new String(output, 0, i);

Comment: @Thomas Not strictly necessary. The char array will be initialized with `\0` and `new String ()` will cut off at the first `\0`.

Comment: @Tomalak True, although the NUL characters are still there and form part of the resulting String object.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable so its not good to try and use them very dynamically try using StringBuilder instead of String and use all of its wonderful methods! It will let you do anything you want. Plus yes if you have something your trying to do, figure out the regex for it and it will work a lot better for you.

Comment: I saw someone downvoted you. It's probably because this would serve better as a comment than as an answer

Comment: @sunrize920 The vote-count is +0/-0. No downvotes have been cast.

Comment: @hexafraction it got removed

Comment: I felt the same way, since I'm new to this site I couldn't find the comment button for his question. So I just did it below in the answer box. Sorry about that.

Comment: I didn't eveen think about the fact that you don't have enough rep to comment. I just hate when people downvote but dont leave a comment as to why.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is good when you build a string from pieces. Splitting the string into pieces by regex and re-assembling it might be a good strategy. I believe `String.replaceAll` does something like this internally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` as

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("[,.;!?(){}\\[\\]<>%]", "");

System.out.println(
   "f,i.l;t!e?r(e)d {s}t[r]i<n>g%".replaceAll(
                   "[,.;!?(){}\\[\\]<>%]", "")); // prints "filtered string"
```

Comment: @Pshemo, Jerry: Oh, I'm left embarrassed. Thanks for pointing out though :)

Comment: @Pshemo's character class variant should actually be a lot faster than listing everything with alternatives. Plus, it's more easily readable (due to the smaller number of escapes).

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code will iterate over all characters of `tmp` and compare them with **all possible** characters that you want to remove, so it will use
`number of tmp characters` x `number or characters you want to remove` comparisons.

To optimize your code you could use short circuit OR `||` and do something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : tmp.toCharArray()) {
    if (!(c == ',' || c == '.' || c == ';' || c == '!' || c == '?'
            || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '['
            || c == ']' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '%'))
        sb.append(c);
}
tmp = sb.toString();
```

or like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] badChars = ",.;!?(){}[]<>%".toCharArray();

outer: 
for (char strChar : tmp.toCharArray()) {
    for (char badChar : badChars) {
        if (badChar == strChar)
            continue outer;// we skip `strChar` since it is bad character
    }
    sb.append(strChar);
}
tmp = sb.toString();
```

This way you will iterate over every `tmp` characters but number of comparisons for that character can decrease if it is not `%` (because it will be last comparison, if character would be `.` program would get his result in one comparison).

---

If I am not mistaken this approach is used with [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[...]`) so maybe try it this way

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,.;!?(){}\\[\\]<>%]"); //store it somewhere so 
                                         //you wont need to compile it again
tmp = p.matcher(tmp).replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation of the [regex] pattern in your code, for example: _replaces all characters that are not letters of the alphabet nor digits with an empty string thus effectively removing those characters_

Comment: I edited it accordingly thanks

Comment: Seems to be a problem as your edit only appears in the revisions and not in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
tmp.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

to remove punctuation

Comment: this will also remove spaces... and probably many other characters that OP doesn't want to remove like `"`

Comment: `\W` stands for Anything that isn't a letter, number or underscore !!!It would be better if you can make the regex more specific .

Comment: No, this is not good. `[\W]` means `[^\A-Za-z_0-9]` which means this solution will also remove letters like `é`.  At least use _something_ that respects Unicode and is not so ASCII-centric!