# Removing punctuation marks in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and I need help converting words to lower case after you get it from a user and remove all punctuation marks from a token before you return it as a word. A punctuation mark is anything that is not a letter or a hyphen. Note that punctuation marks can occur before and after the letters (e.g. This is "an example,which" shows this occurrence). In this example, it should return the words this, is, an, example, which, shows, this, occurrence. Thanks!

Comment: You have to show some effort. Post some code you have written so far to solve this problem by editing your question. StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. Also, there are standard Java functions to make strings lowercase. Please read the [Java String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: I know the basic of how you get an input from user using a scanner and converting that to a lower case but I have no idea how you would go about removing all punctuation marks.

Comment: Try doing some reading on regular expressions and how to use them in Java.

Answer (score 0):

To make lowercase

```
string.toLowerCase()
```

You can use a regex to replace all punctuation characters with spaces

**DISCLAIMER**: this code was tested using Perl and replacing spaces with dashes, not Java replacing punctuation with spaces (so technically it's untested). However, `\p{Punct}` should match all punctuation, according to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\p{Punct}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
string = m.replaceAll(" ");
String words[] = string.split(" "); //if you need it
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good answer to your question: 
[Efficiently removing specific characters (some punctuation) from Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531362/efficiently-removing-specific-characters-some-punctuation-from-strings-in-java)

also, if you need to split the words you can use [guava splitters](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)

Answer (score 0):

Removing characters is simple using `replaceAll`. You just need to write a regular expression which suits your needs.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sentence = "Hi! I'm a sentence with (some) Punctuation.";
        String reduced = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^\\s\\w]", "");
        System.out.println(reduced);
    }
}
```

This prints `hi im a sentence with some punctuation`. If you need different replacements, just replace the regex with a different one, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html