# Java & RegEx: clean and Split a String

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String which contains formatted Decimal values like 45,890.00, 1.5v 2,12g, etc. Additionaly, it contains special characters, HTML entitites (escaped and unescaped) UTF-8 encoded characters, etc all in one line. While I've managed to cleanup the entities, I'm still struggling to come up witha  way to make sure that splitting on spaces or punctuation doesn't split a number which is delimited by a comma or period.

**Example String**:

```
> String original_str = 
>     "a,b;c.d+e-f/g\h*i~j=k?l$m 1.5 1,5 1.5v 1,5v 1255,456.78 & 6<7 &amp; 6&gt;5 &#1602; f&uuml;r; {AGB's;} ([für]); ";
```

**expected Output:**

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> etc
>
> 1.5
>
> 1,5
>
> 1.5v
>
> 1,5v
>
> 1255,456.78
>
> 6<7
>
> 6>5
>
> ق
>
> für
>
> AGB's
>
> für

Number formats can be: x.x OR xxx,xxxx.xxxx,xxxx seperated by **COMMA** | **DOT** | **MIXED**

After cleaning entities out of the String, I try to split it by a list of punctuation characters and spaces, but how do I keep decimal-like-keywords (1,5 1.5v 22,33.66 ..etc) while splitting by commas and periods?

Comment: The way the site works is that you post your code and your analysis of what you think it's doing and we help you.  We don't normally write the code for you.

Comment: @TonyEnnis It's not the best worded question, but his problem is really, "How do I split on comma and dot delimiters without interrupting punctuated numbers?" For that, we provide regex or small code sample support all the time.

Comment: I know.  But he should attempt a solution.

Comment: sorry for my english, but i don't want a Code from you, and as Jeff Ferland said, i need the Correct RegEx for handling any Decimal-Like-keywords? if i use "(\\d,)?(\\d.)" i get 1.5 but what about 1.5v ?

Comment: @Rami.Q I've cleaned things up a bit. Hopefully you'll get some upvotes back. I hope my answer helps as well.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, i tested your RegEx and it works very fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with the pattern

```
.split("[^0-9][.,]|[.,][^0-9]|\\s+|(?![.,])\\p{Punct}")
```

That will split anything that doesn't have a number on both sides of a period or comma, or any other punctuation that isn't a period or comma. The 3rd section between pipes covers any spaces. That last part is based on a negative lookahead which is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200935/90322) to prevent the already matched commas and periods that we kept safe from splitting numbers from being matched here.