# Check if string is a punctuation character

Tags: java, string-comparison, punctuation

Let's say I have a String array that contains some letters and punctuation

```
String letter[] = {"a","b","c",".","a"};
```

In letter[3] we have "."

How can I check if a string is a punctuation character?
We know that there are many possible punctuation characters (,.?! etc.)

My progress so far:

```
for (int a = 0; a < letter.length; a++) {
    if (letter[a].equals(".")) { //===>> i'm confused in this line
        System.out.println ("it's punctuation");
    } else {
        System.out.println ("just letter");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use regex for this purpose. It comes really handy.

Comment: @smit , can you give me a hint?

Comment: This will give you some idea: [Punctuation Regex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200908/punctuation-regex-in-java)

Comment: @sephtian Sorry for late reply. Although I added answer if you want to make use of it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you want to check more punctuations other than just `.`?

If so you can do this.

```
String punctuations = ".,:;";//add all the punctuation marks you want.
...
if(punctuations.contains(letter[a]))
```

Comment: This solution implies that you manually specify all punctuation marks. The definition of 'punctuation' is definitely incomplete.

Comment: This is not enough. There are lots of languages that have different punctuation signs. These not even cover the Latin Alphabet. 
Use \p{P} or \p{Punctuation} instead

Comment: This is incomplete and improper solution @Hans Brende should be selected as correct ans

Answer (score 66):

Here is one way to do it with regular expressions:

```
if (Pattern.matches("\\p{Punct}", str)) {
    ...
}
```

The `\p{Punct}` regular expression is a POSIX pattern representing a single *punctuation character*.

Answer (score 33):

Depending on your needs, you could use either

```
Pattern.matches("\\p{Punct}", str)
```

or

```
Pattern.matches("\\p{IsPunctuation}", str)
```

The first pattern matches the following 32 characters: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``

The second pattern matches a whopping 632 unicode characters, including, for example: `«`, `»`,  `¿`, `¡`, `§`, `¶`, `‘`, `’`, `“`, `”`, and `‽`.

Interestingly, **not all of the 32 characters matched by the first pattern are matched by the second**. The second pattern does *not* match the following 9 characters: `$`, `+`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `^`, `` ` ``, `|`, and `~` (which the first pattern *does* match).

If you want to match for any character from *either* character set, you could do:

```
Pattern.matches("[\\p{Punct}\\p{IsPunctuation}]", str)
```

Comment: Where is Pattern coming from in this example? I"m getting an error "VM718:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Pattern is not defined"

Comment: @Parseltongue this answer is for Java, not javascript

Answer (score 3):

Try this method: Character.isLetter(). It returns true if the character is a letter (a-z, uppercase or lowercase), returns false if character is numeric or symbol.

e.g. boolean answer = Character.isLetter('!');

answer will be equal to false.

Comment: the problem with that solution is when you are checking for special chars like % ^$ .. you will always get false and they are not letters

Comment: @mebada what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried regex: "`[\\p{Punct}]`" or "`[\\p{IsPunctuation}]`" or withouth `[]`, it doesn't work as expected.

My string is:
`How are you?`, or even `"How are you?", he asked.`

Then call: `my_string.matches(regex);` but it seems like it only recognises if the string is only one punctuation (e.g "`?`", "`.`",...).

Only this regex works for me: "`(.*)[\\p{P}](.*)`", it will include all preceding and proceeding characters of the punctuation because the `matches()` requires to match all the sentence.

Answer (score -3):

import String
...
if(string.punctuation.contains(letter[a]))

Answer (score -5):

```js
function has_punctuation(str) {

  var p_found = false;
  var punctuations = '`~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?-=[]\;\'.\/,';
  $.each(punctuations.split(''), function(i, p) {
    if (str.indexOf(p) != -1) p_found = true;
  });

  return p_found;

}
```

Comment: this question asked for java, not javascript.