# Check if string begins with punctuation (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

How can I check if my data string begins with a punctuation mark using Javascript? I looked at [Check if string is a punctuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925454/check-if-string-is-a-punctuation-character) and [How to know that a string starts/ends with a specific string in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715309/how-to-know-that-a-string-starts-ends-with-a-specific-string-in-jquery) and a number of others, but I can't tell where I'm going wrong.

Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
      var punctuations = [".", ",", ":", "!", "?"];

      if (d.endContext.startsWith(punctuations)) {console.log(d.endContext)
      } else {console.log('false')};
```

I only get 'false' returns, but if I pass in "." in

```
if(d.endContext.startsWith('.'))
...
```

I get correct results. I also tried

```
     String punctuations = ".,:;?!"
```

like [Check if string is a punctuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925454/check-if-string-is-a-punctuation-character) suggested, but both Chrome and Firefox gave me error messages ("Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier" and "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement", respectively). It seemed like that error was usually for writing multiline strings in Javascript, which I don't think I'm trying to do. d.endContext will print multi-line strings, but it works fine when I just pass ".", so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: use RegExp to test the string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

using Regex is much simpler.

```
    var str = '.abc'
    var result = !!str.match(/^[.,:!?]/)
    
    console.log(result)
```

- `/` indicates start/end of Regular expression
- `^` means 'start with'
- `[]` means 'character set'. it will match any characters between `[` and `]`
- `!!` converts what `match` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) to a boolean. If it returns a match, it is converted to `true`. If it returns `null`, it is converted to false.

Additionally, this app is quite good to learn Regex!
http://regexr.com/

Have a nice day! :D

Comment: would be nice if you could explain what the `!!` does - and what the regex means in detail.

Comment: This worked for me, but I agree that some explanation about !! would help!

Comment: @low, @west, I think Rokt3r’s `!!` can only be a sequence of two `not` operators, meaning a no-op. I’ll try to remove it, see if anyone objects…

Answer (score 5):

Use the `some` and `startsWith` methods.

```
 punctuations.some(function(character) {
     return string.startsWith(character)
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.
>   Or you can also use regex

```
/[.,:!?]/.test(string.charAt(0))
```

Comment: @Praveen Kumar - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some  I didn't know about this either, but it looks super useful

Comment: Yeah, I just posted a link. It's part of ES6 I think

Answer (score 3):

Using [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is probably the simplest:

```
var punctuations = [".", ",", ":", "!", "?"];
var stringToSearch = d.endContext;  // Your string to search
if (punctuations.indexOf(stringToSearch.charAt(0)) !== -1) {
    // Your awesome code goes here
}
```

It's compatible to IE9 and pretty much all Chrome and Firefox (down to 1.5) versions but if you are using jQuery, you can use [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for further backwards compatibility.

---

Or... just for fun you could go the other end, be cutting edge, and break all non-beta browsers with the new ES7 [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
var punctuations = [".", ",", ":", "!", "?"];
var stringToSearch = d.endContext;  // Your string to search
if (punctuations.includes(stringToSearch.charAt(0))) {
    // Your awesome code goes here
}
```

Compatible with:

- Chrome 47 (not yet released)
- Firefox 43 (not yet released)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a beautiful solution:

```
var punctuations = [".", ",", ":", "!", "?"];
var punkyString = ".hello!";
var nonPunkyString = "hello!";

function isPunkyString(str) {
  return punctuations.indexOf(str[0]) > -1;
}

console.log(punkyString, "is punky:", isPunkyString(punkyString));
console.log(nonPunkyString, "is punky:", isPunkyString(nonPunkyString));
```

**Unit tests!**

```
var punkyStrings = punctuations.map(function (item) {
    return item + " <---<< Punctuations!"
});

var nonPunkyStrings = punctuations.map(function (item, i) {
    return i + " <---<< No punctuations!"
});

punkyStrings.forEach(function (item, i) {
    console.log("Expect", "isPunkyString(\"" + item + "\")", "to be true:", isPunkyString(item));
});

nonPunkyStrings.forEach(function (item, i) {
    console.log("Expect", "isPunkyString(\"" + item + "\")", "to be false:", isPunkyString(item));
});
```

Why is it beautiful? Because I have used the word `punky`! :D Oh and I treat the string as an array. Which is nice!

Has anyone else unit tested their code? :D