# Check if the last char is dot (.)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the last character of an input (`type="number"`) value is a dot!

Tried these, but it doesn't work:

```
let amount = $("#amount").val();
let last_char = amount.slice(-1);
if(last_char == ".")
{
    return;
}
```

Also tried `amount[amount.length-1]` and `charAt()`

P.S. Input type is `type="number"`

## Edit:

None of the answers work: https://jsfiddle.net/dne37hao/

Comment: What's the use case here? You could use regex to detect the period, look here for a succinct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657021/check-if-string-begins-with-punctuation-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

Comment: @User863 It is not a duplicate: https://jsfiddle.net/dne37hao/

Comment: @J.Doe Technically `3.` is equal to `3` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852244/how-to-get-the-raw-value-an-input-type-number-field

Comment: The problem here isn't the matching for the last character. The problem is that, whilst reading the field value with a dot in the end its being interpreted as an empty field. So that's why your checks for the last character are not matching. This question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677323/html5-input-type-number-value-is-empty-in-webkit-if-has-spaces-or-non-numeric-ch

Answer (score 3):

```js
const string = 'Is this a question.';

console.log(string.endsWith('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can achieve this using different ways but with different performance,*

**1.** Using bracket notation:

```
var str = "Test";
var lastLetter = str[str.length - 1];
```

But it's not recommended to use brackets.

**2.** charAt[index]:

```
var lastLetter = str.charAt(str.length - 1)
```

This is readable and fastest among others. It is most recommended way.

**3.** substring:

str.substring(str.length - 1);

**4.** slice:

```
if(str.slice(-1)=== '.'){
return true
}
```

It's slightly faster than substring.The most efficient one

**With ES6:**

You can use `str.endsWith("t");`

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: @adiga can you please elaborate? how it does't answer his question. i have listed down 4 different methods with examples and performance.

Comment: The issue is caused by `type="number"` in the input. `.val()` will ignore the trailing dot. Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = 'Check if the last char is dot.';

if (str.last() === '.') {  // OR just: str.at(-1) === '.'
  return true;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
  value() {
    return this.at(-1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
let amount = $("#amount").val();
if(amount[amount.length-1] === "."){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: what value are you getting in amount variable  any example ?

Comment: For example: `1.` `36.` it doesn't skip these. input type is also number

Comment: So jquery .val() method return string, javascript convert number to string and ignore the . in the end. so if you print amount in console it never show dot(.) in the end, change input type as text then you can check if input has a dot in the end or not.

Comment: Number can not end with dot in javascript, javascript basically ignore . in the end of the number