# Does Java has primitive punctuation string (or list) as string.punctuation in Python?

Tags: java, python, string, punctuation

Python string class has a string property named punctuation, and it contains almost all the punctuation I need to deal with.

It looks like:

```
import string
print string.punctuation          #!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I wonder whether Java also has this string property, in any classes come with Java?

Comment: As far as i know not directly in the String class, but the regex pattern can identify a punctuation character like given in the second answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925454/check-if-string-is-a-punctuation-character)

Comment: Who is "we" in this case? Punctuation requirements will vary significantly by culture and use case.

Comment: @jonSkeet Thanks, editted.

Comment: As @Kevin Esche says, _java.util.regex.Pattern_ supports "\p{Punct}" Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

Comment: Well how do we know which punctuation *you* need to deal with? If you just want *those* punctuation characters, you can easily define your own constant... but are you sure you don't need to support other cultures?