# Regex for all Symbols except for |

Tags: java, regex, symbols

Is there a way to use the patter `\p{Punct}` in a regex in Java without the Symbol `|`. 
I tried `\\p{Punct}&&[^|]`, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you put that inside a character class? I.e. `[\\p{Punct}&&[^|]]`, because the `&&` syntax works only inside those.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is nearly correct. The correct syntax is:

```
[\\p{Punct}&&[^|]]
```

Answer (score 0):

do you try with this class : `[^\\P{Punct}|]` (note the uppercase P)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this question: [Punctuation Regex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200908/punctuation-regex-in-java)?

I think you can modify that answer slightly to use `(?![|])\\p{Punct}`