# How to avoid punctuationduring tokenization using Stanford NLP

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp, punctuation

I am using standford  core NLP. I have tried the following example. this example can tokenize the words from the text. However it also extract punctuation  such as comma, full stop etc. I was wondering how to set the properties that allow not to extract punctuation or alternatively is there any other  way to do the same. Here is the code example. I know its easy using Python but not sure how to do it in Java. Please suggest.

```
    props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String text = "this is simple text written in English,Spanish etc."

// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

   pipeline.annotate(document);

   List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

   for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
     for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
    // this is the text of the token
    String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't have any tokenizer option for skipping these, but it shouldn't be difficult. Punctuation strings are a closed class.

You could match tokens which are punctuation using a regular expression. (Use `\p{Punct}`; see e.g. [Punctuation Regex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8200908/176075) ). Then just drop tokens whose text content matches such a regex.

Comment: thanks , What about the stop words, how to discard the stop words , are they also not available as options?

Comment: They are not available as a standard feature, because the definition of a stopword is not very concrete / it's task-specific. You can build your own stopword list or find one on the internet and manually filter stopword tokens in the same way you do punctuation tokens.